# gstreamer video tearing on multiple slices per frame over UDP

Tags: udp, gstreamer, h.264, rtp, tegra

For bandwidth reasons I've modified the slice-header spacing to use more slices per I-frame, **this causes tearing on the receiving end.**

The problem appears as if individual slices are getting decoded without an entire I-frame getting buffered up for the omxh264dec? This is a bit strange as the Tegra decoder is supposed to only work on a frame level..

Perhaps this problem can be alleviated by correct synchronization of GstBuffer:s on the receiving end?

**Repro case: (Jetson TX2)**

```
# Sender:
gst-launch-1.0 nvcamerasrc ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, format=(string)I420, framerate=(fraction)60/1' ! nvvidconv flip-method=0 ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), format=(string)I420' ! omxh264enc iframeinterval=1 bit-packetization=TRUE slice-header-spacing=450000 control-rate=2 preset-level=0 profile=1 qp-range=-1,-1:10,10:-1,-1 ! 'video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream' ! h264parse ! rtph264pay mtu=60000 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000

# Reciever:
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! "application/x-rtp,encoding-name=H264,payload=96" ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink async=TRUE sync=TRUE
```

Comment: No `rtpjitterbuffer`? Maybe make use of the `rtpbin` convenience element?

Comment: The rtpjitterbuffer solves this issue!

Answer (score 0):

As Florian Zwoch suggested an rtpjitterbuffer solves this issue.